# How can an unbounded PCollection be immutable?

Tags: apache-beam

I am getting started in dataflow/apache beam, and I'm struggling to understand a concept. According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/PCollection.html) :

> A PCollection is an immutable collection of values of type T. A PCollection can contain either a bounded or unbounded number of elements.

It is easy to understand that bounded PCollections are immutable. You get a file, you put it in a PCollection, you can't change it: Immutable.

What about unbounded PCollections? They are by definition, without a limit of number of elements, so stuff always gets added to them indefinitely; i.e. How can something be changed perpetually and also be immutable?

An explanation would be great.

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question! I believe the [Programming Guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#immutability) explains PCollection's immutability better than the JavaDoc. The immutability has to do with individual elements:

> A PCollection is immutable. Once created, you cannot add, remove, or change **individual elements**. A Beam Transform might process each element of a PCollection and generate new pipeline data (as a new PCollection), but it does not consume or modify the original input collection.
>
> Note: Beam SDKs avoid unnecessary copying of elements, so PCollection contents are logically immutable, not physically immutable. Changes to input elements may be visible to other DoFns executing within the same bundle, and may cause correctness issues. As a rule, it’s not safe to modify values provided to a DoFn.

Comment: Your definition also says **Once created, you cannot add individual elements**

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at it is that the set is logically immutable, it's just your view into it that's changing over time (due to the inability to see into the future). E.g. `ReadFromPubSub` returns the (immutable, unbounded) set of all message that will ever be published to this topic. From the Beam API you can't modify this set as a PCollection, but you can create other immutable, unbounded PCollections that are derived from it.

This is similar to lazy, infinite structures that exist in functional language like [Haskell](https://hernandis.me/2019/10/20/haskell-infinite-structures.html)--you can only ever observe a portion of it, but that doesn't mean the whole thing doesn't exist as an immutable object.